# Solving $u_{\xi\eta} = 0$ and differentiability conditions on solutions

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

After transformation someone often encounters the PDE
$$
 u_{\xi\eta} = 0
$$
but I am quite confused about the differentiability conditions of its solution (for example  [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548124/pde-transformation-in-normal-form) I read different versions). I know it could be solved by first integrating with respect to $\eta$, yielding
$$
 u_{\xi} = g(\xi)
$$
for some differentiable function $g$, then integration with respect to $\xi$ yields
$$
 u = G(\xi) + f(\eta)
$$
for some function $f$, and everything that is needed is that $G(\xi)$ is differentiable, and for $g$ and $f$ I do not see that any differentiability conditions are necessary. Also if I solve
$$
 u_{\eta\xi} = 0
$$
which is (by Schwartz) equivalent to the above I get everything reversed, namely
$$
 u = g(\xi) + F(\eta)
$$
where $F$ has to be differentiable, but in the above mentioned post it is said in the answer that the general solution is
$$
 u = F(\xi) + G(\eta)
$$
where $F,G \in C^2$, in other sources, for example [this wiki entry on d'Alembert formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula), I read that it has the general solution
$$
 u = F(\xi) + G(\eta)
$$
for $F,G \in C^1$. So everywhere I read it differently... So could anyone explain to me how these differentiability conditions follow, what are the correct conditions, and how they relate to the above mentioned derivations?